# DateDiff doesn’t work with nullables

Tags: vb.net

I’m trying to find the difference between nullable dates. `DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, firstDate, secondDate)` works for `Date`, but not for `Nullable(Of Date)`. Both my dates are nullable fields.

This is the error message:

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible `DateDiff` can be called without a narrowing conversion:
>
> - `Public Function DateDiff(Interval As String, Date1 As Object, Date2 As Object, [DayOfWeek As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FirstDayOfWeek = FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday], [WeekOfYear As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FirstWeekOfYear = FirstWeekOfYear.Jan1]) As Long`: Argument matching parameter `Interval` narrows from `Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateInterval` to `String`.
> - `Public Function DateDiff(Interval As Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateInterval, Date1 As Date, Date2 As Date, [DayOfWeek As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FirstDayOfWeek = FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday], [WeekOfYear As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FirstWeekOfYear = FirstWeekOfYear.Jan1]) As Long`: Argument matching parameter `Date1` narrows from `Date?` to `Date`.
> - `Public Function DateDiff(Interval As Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateInterval, Date1 As Date, Date2 As Date, [DayOfWeek As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FirstDayOfWeek = FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday], [WeekOfYear As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FirstWeekOfYear = FirstWeekOfYear.Jan1]) As Long`: Argument matching parameter `Date2` narrows from `Date?` to `Date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know they’re not `Nothing`, get their values:

```
DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, firstDate.Value, secondDate.Value)
```

But you can take advantage of [operator overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1905yhe2.aspx), since this isn’t VB6:

```
(secondDate.Value - firstDate.Value).Days
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to call the `.Value` on the nullable `Date` object.

```
DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, firstDate.Value, secondDate.Value)
```

Answer (score -1):

2 Years Late to Answer the question.... :)

The error Above could be caused by a data type miss match.
Use DateValue function e.g

```
DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, DateValue(stringwiDate.text), DateValue(string2witDate.text))
```